# Android NDK - fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker-errors, zlib

I can't include the Android NDK native library zlib header **zlib.h**: I get a *fatal error:

> **zlib.h: No such file or directory**

when running `mka hello_world`.

I am compiling using CyanogenMod mka build command (this is Android NDK).

`Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
LOCAL_MODULE      := hello_world  
LOCAL_LDLIBS      := -lz
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

test.c (zlib not needed here but this is for the example):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <zlib.h>
int main()
{
     printf("Hello World\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Debug information - full command (mka showcommands):

```
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I external/test -I /home/me/cm/out/target/product/galaxysmtd/obj/EXECUTABLES/hello_world_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper  -isystem system/core/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem hardware/ril/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem external/skia/include -isystem /home/me/cm/out/target/product/galaxysmtd/obj/include -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libstdc++/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/common -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/arch-arm -isystem bionic/libm/include -isystem bionic/libm/include/arm -isystem bionic/libthread_db/include -c  -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -msoft-float -fpic -fPIE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -include build/core/combo/include/arch/linux-arm/AndroidConfig.h -I build/core/combo/include/arch/linux-arm/ -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-builtin-sin -fno-strict-volatile-bitfields -Wno-psabi -mthumb-interwork -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -DNEEDS_VECTORIMPL_SYMBOLS -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -fgcse-after-reload -frerun-cse-after-loop -frename-registers -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing       -MD -MF /home/me/cm/out/target/product/galaxysmtd/obj/EXECUTABLES/hello_world_intermediates/test.d -o /home/me/cm/out/target/product/galaxysmtd/obj/EXECUTABLES/hello_world_intermediates/test.o external/test/test.c
```

Debug information - env vars:

```
ANDROID_BUILD_PATHS="/home/me/cm/out/host/linux-x86/bin:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/mips/mipsel-linux-android-4.7/bin:/home/me/cm/development/emulator/qtools:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin:/home/me/cm/development/scripts:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/devtools/tools:"
ANDROID_BUILD_TOP="/home/me/cm"
ANDROID_DEV_SCRIPTS="/home/me/cm/development/scripts:/home/me/cm/prebuilts/devtools/tools"
ANDROID_EABI_TOOLCHAIN="/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin"
ANDROID_HOST_OUT="/home/me/cm/out/host/linux-x86"
ANDROID_JAVA_TOOLCHAIN="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin"
ANDROID_PRE_BUILD_PATHS="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:"
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT="/home/me/cm/out/target/product/galaxysmtd"
ANDROID_PROMPT_PREFIX="[arm-cm_galaxysmtd-userdebug]"
ANDROID_QTOOLS="/home/me/cm/development/emulator/qtools"
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN="/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin"
ARM_EABI_TOOLCHAIN="/home/me/cm/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin"
```

The workaround is to use compile the zlib shared library, but why should I do it as it's supposed to be a standard "stable" NDK library!

Note [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/VwsGXb8tzTI/GPxWM6H6TnkJ) didn't help:

> Yes, sorry about that but this is really a bug in the NDK build
>   scripts. Right now, you can replace:
>
> `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz`
>
> with
>
> `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -lz`
>
> sorry about that, this will be fix in the next NDK release.

Comment: Actually, Android NDK does include "zlib.h" in usual **include** directory for all platforms. I guess the error is with CyanogenMod build system which does not use the "official" NDK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems line it's a bug. We need to use a workaround by building and including [`android_external_zlib`](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_zlib). If finally used CyanogenMod build system with these adds in my module `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../zlib/src
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  += libz
```

But for the massive audience of this question (3k+ views), someone should post a full solution based on Android NDK solely.

Source: [@KrisWebDev](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23182819/3)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing zlib header files, try installing `libz-dev` development package, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
```

Comment: I don't get it. What's up with your recent "install libz-dev" answer spree? How does this debian-based answer do this universally? Why did you add an answer here 20 minutes after adding a self-answer on behalf of OP (which you were very right to do so)?

Comment: Multiple answers are fine. I've reposted OP answer from the question, because this is the right place to post, but I'm not sure if his approach is ultimate solution to the problem. This one solves `zlib.h: No such file or directory` error straight by installing missing development package which provide header files for `zlib`. Apt-get is pretty common, depending where you're developing your Android apps. I could see OP is using Linux based on the paths.

Comment: As far as I know, apt-get only applies to debian and ubuntu by default. I can accept that this is a valid answer to all these questions, but are you sure that none of them can be closed as duplicates of each other, then? The main caveat with (near-)duplicate answers on multiple questions (which my original question referred to) is that if the same answer applies, then the questions are often duplicates, in which case closure is the right action to take. I'm not saying you're necessarily wrong, I just want you to make sure you're doing the right thing.

Comment: Ah, I just found another one of yours, where you voted to close as dupe, *then* answered with the same thing after 7 minutes. This is my issue.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I've marked these which could be duplicated, but some of them they had different context and different OSes. Some of them relate to Vagrant specifically, OS X, another for Ruby, or Android, so they're not really duplicated, but they have common issue, missing zlib header file. These are my guesses that the Makefile wasn't generated properly because of missing header file package, since I've confirmed this solution on Ubuntu having this problem my-self. I've posted in few places to help people find the problem quickly, since most of the answers weren't clear.